# how to get 'price' serialize data using list comprehension method?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

the `product_ser.data` are printing this much in a `list of tuple`:

```
[OrderedDict([('price', 1)]), OrderedDict([('price', 25)]), OrderedDict([('price', 1)]), OrderedDict([('price', 75)])]
```

views.py :

```
#get price_data
data = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
product_ser = FilterPriceSerializer(data,many=True)
filter_PriceData=[]
# print(product_ser.data)
min_price = min(product_ser.data, key=lambda x:x['price'])
max_price = max(product_ser.data, key=lambda x:x['price'])

filter_PriceData.append({"min_price":min_price, "max_price":max_price})
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you give us an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
product_ser = FilterPriceSerializer(data, many=True)
all_price = [price["price"] for price in product_ser.data]
```

Comment: i want to get all the `price` data that inside `product_ser.data`

Comment: do not use loops, tell me if you can solve this using `list comprehension` method

Comment: that would be `product_ser.data` in list comprehension. please update it on your answer.